# node or npm: How to see the source code of a package installed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Like in python i install a package using

```
pip install django
```

inside a virtualenv,

Then it puts all the files in `site-packages` folder. and then i can import the package using

```
from django.core import mail
```

But i can easily browse the code of django/core in `site-packages`

Similarly if I install a package using npm can i see the source of that

Eg:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
```

Now i want to see the `react` file and go through the React and useEffect

Is it possible

Comment: Are you meaning `node_modules` dir?

Comment: I think they are in node_modules. if I find for react.js can i find

Answer (score 0):

I do not have background in Python. So, can't explain or compare in Python way. But, yes! You can read or *go through* the source code in most of the cases.

Now, talking about the specific example you mentioned in question - React. Things are little complicated as we're talking about one of the popular library. You may wouldn't find `React.js` or `react.js` file directly. But, that doesn't mean you can read the source code. Let's do it.

1. Create an application that has `react` as dependency (You can create an application using `create-react-app`).
2. In this application, you'll have `node_modules` folder. Within this `node_modules`, you'll have folder after the name of dependency e.g. `react`. Go inside this folder.
3. You'll find the `package.json` file. Open it and look for `main`. The `main` is an entry point of the program/package. It mentioned `index.js`. So, let's open the `index.js` file.
4. If you open the `index.js`, you'll see that based on environment, they're requiring the `react.production.min.js` or `react.development.js` file. Open this `react.development.js` file from `cjs` folder.
5. In this file, do a search for `useEffect`. You will find a function with the same name.

But, I wouldn't recommended you to read the code in this way, if you're planning for React. You may try [this](https://github.com/numbbbbb/read-react-source-code) solution. Also, if you're planning to read the source code as starting point, why not start with simple and easy to read packages? And don't forget that if not all then most of the packages are there on GitHub and on NPM website, you'll see the link for the Repository.